# Rename csv file removing the date

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch-file, csv, vbscript

i need to rename a csv file and remove the date:

I have **file_20170101.csv** (The date will change every day)
and i need just to keep **file.csv**

How can i make this as a bat file in order to run it every day (from windows task manager).

cheers
Antonio

Comment: So you want to overwrite the file.csv from previous day without a backup? See `For %%A in (file_*.csv) do for /f "delims=_" %%B in (%%A) Do Echo New name "%%B%%~xA"`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution via the command line should be:

```
ren file_*.csv file.csv
```

Caution: This will rename any file matching the pattern, thus leading to conflicts if two or more of your files are present. The command will execute though, renaming the first file it matches.

Just save this as .bat and execute it in the right directory. If you use the Task Scheduler add the start in field.

[image]

Comment: Tks awerno

I have backup file.
When i run directly the bacth, it changes the file name to file.csv, however, when i set the task scheduler, it will not change the file name.

any guess?

Comment: Probably because the task scheduler doesn't know the directory it should execute the command in. Add the full path to the command or add the "Start in" field of the scheduler.

Comment: Full path is ok.

is the any other way to do this? vbs?

tks

Comment: Simplest solution: Save the command as in my answer and 'Start in' field with the correct path.

Comment: @AntonioCaeiro did it work?

Answer (score 0):

No extra backup. Simply change the line `CD /D ...` to fit your environment. I hope the path isn't one only available via a mapping the scheduled account doesn't know.

```
@Echo off
CD /D "X:\path\to\folder\"
For %%A in (file_*.csv
  ) do For /F "delims=_" %%B in ("%%A"
    ) Do Echo Move /Y  "%%~fA" "%%~nB%%~xA"
```

If you execute locally the batch you see the commands which will be executed once you remove the echo in the last line.